# How to generate PHP & MySQL data and have it display in an XML file?

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I was wondering how can I display PHP & MySQL generated data in an XML file like a sitemap?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Apache, the way I do it is:

`AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .xml`

Notice the **.xml** This allows the server to process php content in .xml extension files. So then make a foobar.xml file and have php generate your .xml

Another option is to create a script to generate the .xml every day or however often. Probably the safer option with less issues

Comment: `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .xml` but wouldn't that change all php files i just want to change one file?

Comment: it doesn't change php files. it just allows all .xml files to be treated as php file. You can restrict it in a .htaccess file and only certain files. http://www.howtoforge.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-4489.html is an older post, but it covers both options. The problem is some bots will complain if it's expecting a xml file, but the sitemap doesn't have a .xml extension.